# FontAwesome icon not visible, but works on another same view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I have a weird problem: one of my FontAwesome icons is not showing up although all other icons on the view work. I can't figure out why.

```
<a class="add-img fa fa-plus-circle" title="@SharedResources.Index.Add" data-bind="click: mainDataAdd"></a>
```

- i've checked that icon is properly named
- tried another icon class, didn't work

No matter which icon I put inside that link, it just doesn't show up.

[image]

```
<tr class="actions-row" role="row">
                        <td class="header-action-row" style="border:none;" colspan="12">
                            <h6 class='datatable-title'><span class='fa fa-list'></span>&nbsp; @SharedResources.Index.SocialWorkerLog</h6>
                            <div class="action-images pull-right">
                                @{
                                    Dictionary<string, string> reports = ReportManager.GetReportList(ReportLocations.ResidentActiviesAllMainGrid_Top.ToString());
                                    if (reports.Count() == 1)
                                    {
                                        <a class="fa fa-print" title="@SharedResources.Index.Print" data-bind="click: function(){printreportSocial('@reports.First().Key',$data);}" style="color:#337ab7; cursor: pointer;"></a>
                                    }
                                }
                                <a class="add-img fa fa-plus-circle" title="@SharedResources.Index.Add" data-bind="click: mainDataAdd"></a>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

Comment: Please provide link

Comment: Can you provide your code in a codepen link? It could be that the icon is transparent.

Comment: `<i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>` add this to inner of `<a hred></a>`

Comment: Add style="color:#337ab7; cursor: pointer;" like you did for the other link.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is fixed. Used below linked font Awesome CDN and give color to anchor tag

```css
a{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />


<a class="add-img fa fa-plus-circle" title="@SharedResources.Index.Add" data-bind="click: mainDataAdd"></a>
```